# Get all root elements where any of the children (or grandchildren) meet condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a self-referenced hierarchy table in my SQL Database which I imported using EntityFramework database-first. And this is the class I get from it:

```
public partial class Dimension
{
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> ParentDimensionId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Dimension> ChildDimensions { get; set; }
    public virtual Dimension ParentDimensions { get; set; }
}
```

The class and references work perfectely. But now I would like to write a LINQ query that allows me to get all root dimensions *(e.g. where the ParentDimensionId == null)* for which there are any children that meet a certain condition.

My problem is, that there could be **n number of levels** in this hierarchy and I have to check this condition for every child, grandchild, etc.

So I really need some extension method like this:

```
List<Dimension> dimensions = db.Dimension.Where(x =>
   x.ParentDimension == null && // This is the "root" identifier
   x.ChildDimensions.AnyChildWhere( c => c.Name == "foo") // This is the condition
).ToList()
```

This "AnyChildWhere" method would of course need to be able to go through the entire n-level hierarchy tree until there were no children left.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about `db.Dimension.SelectMany(d=>d.ChildDimensions).Where(e=>e.ParentDimension == null && x.ChildDimensions.Any());`?

Comment: Thanks for you answer @HariPrasad . But where would I put my actual condition (e.g. c.Name == "foo") for the Children?